# Why am i getting null pointer exception when using map in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception

I am using a `Map` in java i am getting null pointer exception when i use this 
`if(!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(itemsImagesMap.get(item.getuserId()).toString()))`

The map does not contain this userId but i have checked `!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull` but then also i am getting null pointer exception..

Comment: What is MAP? Do you mean java.util.Map? Then, if you nest serveral method invocations without further explanation, it is hard for us to tell what is going on, and which one might cause your NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `item` is `null` and you get the exception since you call `getuserId` on `null` or `itemsImagesMap.get(item.getuserId())` returns `null` and you call `toString` on `null`

Comment: Just check `if(item == null)` or `if(item.getUserId() == null)` to verify

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do some checks in your code. Something like:

```
if (item != null && item.getuserId() != null && itemsImagesMap.get(item.getuserId()) != null) {
  // do the rest of the logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoul -really- avoid arm-long lines ;)

Split it into multiple lines, it will be far more easy to debug.

(Sorry, this does not answer the question, but do this and post the result).

Did you put something corresponding to the item.getuserId() key in your map ?